# How do i get a instance of Vuejs 3 component programatically?

Tags: vuejs3

I am trying to port my Vuejs 2 code to Vuejs 3. I have a Vuejs component "dialogComponent" defined below. In my Vuejs app instance i am trying to instantiate this component programmatically in the Vuejs app's "dialog" method. In the Vuejs 2 world, i can easily do by using Vue.extend(...) as shown below. How do i get the Component instance using Vuejs 3 in "dialog" method?

// mylogic.js

```
var dialogComponent = {
    props: {
        visible: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        type: { type: String, default: 'is-info' },
        title: { type: String, default: 'Confirm' },
        message: { type: String, default: 'Are you sure?' },
        confirmText: { type: String, default: 'Ok' },
        cancelText: { type: String, default: 'Cancel' },
        onConfirm: { type: Function, default: () => { } },
    },
    methods: {
        cancel() {
            this.visible = false;
            this.$emit('cancel');
        },
        confirm() {
            this.visible = false,
                this.$emit('confirm', true);
            this.onConfirm(true, this);
        },
        deactive() {
            this.visible = false;
            this.$emit('cancel');
        },
        close() {
            this.visible = false;
            this.$destroy();
            removeElement(this.$el);
        },
    },
    beforeMount() {
        if (typeof window != 'undefined') {
            this.$nextTick(() => {
                var container = document.querySelector(this.container) || document.body;
                container.appendChild(this.$el);
            });
        }
    },
    mounted() { },
    template: `
        <section class="section">
            <div class="modal" :class="{'is-active': visible}">
                <div class="modal-background" @click="deactive"></div>
                <div class="modal-card">
                    <header class="modal-card-head">
                        <p class="modal-card-title">{{title}}</p>
                        <button class="delete" aria-label="close" @click="cancel"></button>
                    </header>
                    <section class="modal-card-body">
                        <p>{{ message }}</p>
                    </section>
                    <footer class="modal-card-foot">
                        <button class="button" :class="type" @click="confirm">{{confirmText}}</button>
                        <button class="button is-dark" @click="cancel">{{cancelText}}</button>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    `,
};

var alertDetail = {
    data() {
        return {
            isLoading: true,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        delete() {
            this.dialog({
                title: 'Confirm Delete',
                type: 'is-danger',
                visible: true,
                message: "Are you sure you want to delete? This action cannot be undone.",
                onConfirm: () => this.onConfirm(),
            });
        },
        onConfirm() {
            // XMLRequest call to delete
            console.log("successfully deleted");
            this.isLoading = false;
        },
        dialog(propsData = {}) {
            // var Dialog = Vue.extend(dialogComponent); // Vuejs 2 way of doing things
            // TODO: how do i get Component using Vuejs3 API 
            var Dialog = ???
            return new Dialog({el: document.createElement('div'), propsData});
        },
    }, // methods
    mounted() {
        this.$nextTick(function () {
            this.delete();
        });
    }, // mounted
};

Vue.createApp(alertDetail)
    .component('Dialog', dialogComponent)
    .mount('#v-alertdetail');
```

I have tried using this way but i don't think it will give me the component instance:

```
const Dialog = this._context.Dialog;
```

Comment: looks like i can use this function mentioned here: https://github.com/pearofducks/mount-vue-component/blob/master/index.js